# How can I fix the error with my terraform code?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
on main.tf line 30, in resource "aws_route_table" "you-route":
route = [
{
cidr_block                         = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
gateway_id                        = aws_internet_gateway.you-gw.id
route                              = null
carrier_gateway_id                 = ""
destination_prefix_list_id         = ""
egress_only_gateway_id             = ""
instance_id                        = aws_instance.you-instance.id
ipv6_cidr_block                    = ""
local_gateway_id                   = ""
nat_gateway_id                     = ""
network_interface_id               = ""
transit_gateway_id                 = ""
vpc_endpoint_id                    = ""
vpc_peering_connection_id          = ""
},

{
ipv6_cidr_block                    = ["::/0"]
gateway_id                         = aws_internet_gateway.you-gw.id
route                              = null
carrier_gateway_id                 = ""
destination_prefix_list_id         = ""
egress_only_gateway_id             = ""
instance_id                        = aws_instance.you-instance.id
ipv6_cidr_block                    = ""
local_gateway_id                   = ""
nat_gateway_id                     = ""
network_interface_id               = ""
transit_gateway_id                 = ""
vpc_endpoint_id                    = ""
vpc_peering_connection_id          = ""
     }
]
```

aws_instance.you-instance.id will be known only after apply
aws_internet_gateway.you-gw.id will be known only after apply

Inappropriate value for attribute "route": element 0: attribute "cidr_block": string required.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The `cidr_block` should be like this

```
cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
```

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for your candid reply. I had tried that also, still returned same error.

Comment: @BlessedUyo All cidr block should be string, including this`ipv6_cidr_block = "::/0"`

Comment: Yes, I had changed it but, it still didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I am not sure whats with the route error: Inappropriate value for attribute "route": element 0: I do not have a route yes but it is defined in my code to create a route.